# 9 (plus or minus various things) is the opposite of 8

Tags: word, english

Find a word, whose pattern is such that is fits the nine letters as follows. Then change it accordingly so that its pattern becomes eight letters as follows respectively.

`*.***.*****` (9)

`- the first letter of the English language`
`+ urinate`
`- a knot of hair`
`+ allow`
`- body movement with music`
`+ an hour in Spain`

`= *.***.****` (8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer is

> `ABUNDANCE --> PLETHORA`

---

> ```
>  ABUNDANCE
>
>  - the first letter of the English language (A)
>
>  + urinate (P)
>
>  - a knot of hair (BUN)
>
>  + allow (LET)
>
>  - body movement with music (DANCE)
>
>  + an hour in Spain (HORA)
>
>  = PLETHORA
> ```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but it doesn't seem to match the title. I.e Abundance and Plethora are not opposites.

Comment: @Jens I would be very surprised if it's not it. All of these are the first things that came to my mind (without even paying attention to letter counts and patterns) and the fact that they end up making words when put together cannot be a coincidence. Maybe by "opposites" they meant opposite sides of the equals sign or maybe it was a mistake?

Comment: @eyl327 For 'urinate' it is more likely to be as 'Pee'

Comment: @UnidentifiedX That's the word, but the asterisks seem to indicate the number of letters from each part and that would mean a 1-letter answer for urinate. Pee sounds like P.

Comment: @eyl327 Is it possible for it to be the second word?

Comment: @UnidentifiedX "Let" is the second word. I can't think of a better answer for "allow"

Comment: @Jens I'd say they're indicative of opposites, at least. "How much meat do you have?" "An Abundance!" (My family could eat for a year) *good* — "How much meat do you have?" "A Plethora!" (My family was crushed by a truckfull of rotting beef carcasses.) *bad*

Comment: BTW, thanks to everyone on this site for my 25,000!! :)

Comment: @Chowzen Congrats ;)